# Consistent formatting of short index page ranges

Tags: formatting, indexing

MakeIndex allows for special formatting of ranges of two, three, or more than three consecutive pages within index entries. One may (with the help of `.ist` style files) change the range delimiter (by default `--`) or replace delimiter and end page with a suffix like "sqq.". It is also possible to specify a "ranged" index reference for longer text blocks, using, e.g., `\index{bla-par|(}` at the start and `\index{bla-par|)}` at the end of the block. However, formatting of index ranges of exactly two pages is inconsistent: Those created by two "standard" index references on two consecutive pages will use `,` as delimiter (unlike for longer ranges), while those created by a"ranged" reference will use `--`. What must be done that either `,` or `--` will be consistently used for all ranges of exactly two pages?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

Some text.\index{bla}\index{foo}\index{gnu}%
    \index{bla-par|(}\index{bla-par|)}\index{foo-par|(}\index{gnu-par|(}

\clearpage

Some text.\index{foo}\index{gnu}\index{foo-par|)}

\clearpage

Some text.\index{gnu}\index{gnu-par|)}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's possible to coerce MakeIndex into considering an entry falling in only two consecutive pages as an implicit range.

Comment: @egreg OTOH, MakeIndex allows to replace a two-page range with a suffix using `suffix_2p <whatever>` in an `.ist` file.

Comment: `suffix_2p` overwrites `delim_r` but isn't use for your case `foo, 1, 2`

Comment: @Herbert Actually. `suffix_2p "f."` *will* result in `foo, 1f.` for my example.

Comment: @lockstep: sorry, I meant that you do not get 1-2 with `suffix_2p "--"`

Comment: @Herbert No problem. It's rather strange, though, that "suffixing" works for two consecutive pages although `delim_r` does not apply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the page numbers are plain arabic numbers, then the following `.ist` file and some macros split the two-page ranges.

File `pagerangemarkup.ist`:

```
\indexentry{bla}{1}
\indexentry{foo}{1}
\indexentry{gnu}{1}
\indexentry{bla-par|(}{1}
\indexentry{bla-par|)}{1}
\indexentry{foo-par|(}{1}
\indexentry{gnu-par|(textbf}{1}
\indexentry{foo}{2}
\indexentry{gnu}{2}
\indexentry{foo-par|)}{2}
\indexentry{gnu}{3}
\indexentry{gnu-par|)}{3}
one@irwin:~/test> mv pag.ist pagerangemarkup.ist
catone@irwin:~/test> cat pagerangemarkup.ist 
delim_0      ", \\IdxPageBegin "
delim_1      ", \\IdxPageBegin "
delim_2      ", \\IdxPageBegin "
delim_n      "\\IdxPageEnd, \\IdxPageBegin "
delim_r      "\\IdxPageEnd\\IdxRange{--}\\IdxPageBegin "
delim_t      "\\IdxPageEnd"
encap_prefix "\\IdxEncapBegin\\"
encap_infix  "{\\IdxPageBegin "
encap_suffix "\\IdxPageEnd}\\IdxEncapEnd"
```

Test file `test.tex` (I have added `\textbf` to get another test case):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\makeatletter
\def\IdxEncapBegin#1\IdxEncapEnd{#1}
\def\IdxPageBegin{%
  \@ifnextchar\IdxEncapBegin{%
    \IdxPage@UnwrapEncap
  }{%
    \IdxPage@Action
  }%
}
\def\IdxPage@UnwrapEncap#1\IdxEncapEnd\IdxPageEnd{%
  #1\IdxEncapEnd
}
\def\IdxPage@Action#1\IdxPageEnd{%
  \def\IdxPage@LastPage{#1}%
  #1%
}
\def\IdxRange#1\IdxPageBegin#2\IdxPageEnd{%
  \ifnum#2=\numexpr(1+\IdxPage@LastPage)\relax
    , %
  \else
    #1%
  \fi
  #2%
}

\begin{document}

Some text.\index{bla}\index{foo}\index{gnu}%
\index{bla-par|(}\index{bla-par|)}\index{foo-par|(}\index{gnu-par|(textbf}

\clearpage

Some text.\index{foo}\index{gnu}\index{foo-par|)}

\clearpage

Some text.\index{gnu}\index{gnu-par|)}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Call of `makeindex`:

```
makeindex -s pagerangemarkup.ist test
```

> [image: Index]

Answer (score 3):

run `texindy <file>.idx` instead of `makeindex`

Comment: I have never used `xindy` up to now, but it works indeed (using `,` as delimiter), so +1. Could you elaborate a bit if there may be also solutions with MakeIndex or if this is a built-in limitation of MakeIndex?

Comment: I didn't really know, but I suppose that it is a limitation of `makeindex` because I do not know of any parameter which controls this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks -- if no one comes up with a MakeIndex-based solution within a short time, I will accept your answer.